# Instrument in Xcode for temperature monitoring

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, instruments, overheating

Is there any function in Xcode instruments that would show me status of the device temperature while debugging? I have an app that makes the phone go crazy hot and I don't know why. I am not asking why is my app causing my device to overheat - I want to know if there is a way HOW to find out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to get the temperature of the device in Instruments. For that to be possible, the device itself would have to have a temperature sensor, and as far as I know, it does not.

To me, if the device is overheating, that's a problem for the hardware engineers. I doubt anything you change in your app could fix it.

Comment: It does have a temperature sensor, but we're not allowed to get at it. Try overheating your device and you'll get this - http://s.iosfans.com/?u=http://www.ifans.com/forums/imgcache2/38546.png

Answer (score 2):

If your device is getting hot solely because of your app, it's because it's consuming power.  There's nothing else that can heat up your device. The biggest power users on your device are your screen and the radios.  So, are you overusing location services, the camera, bluetooth, endlessly pinging wifi?  Check out the WWDC lectures on power use, you might find your solution there.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably something you're doing with the app itself.
High CPU/GPU/GPS or cell usage would be the most likely culprit.